# How to access abi of deployed contract with truffle?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, abi

I have deployed my contract on rinkeby test network, now I have to connect my contract with the frontend and for this I need to access the ABI of the deployed contract. I am using truffle framework and I saw somewhere that ABI is in the build folder but I can't find it. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the auto-generated json file under the ./build/contracts folder, and then just extract it. For more detailed information you can read this article: https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-get-contract-abi-in-truffle-22d0c0457ceb

Hope it is useful :)